# Client side Response caching in ASP.NET Core middleware

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, caching

In .net core API project , I want to add `cache-control` header in my responses. In order to have **client-side caching**

So I read this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-6.0

and I have added the response cache middleware with profile like below

```
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.CacheProfiles.Add("Default30",
            new CacheProfile()
            {
                Duration = 300000,
                Location = ResponseCacheLocation.Client
            });
    });


    app.UseResponseCaching();
```

and in the `controller.cs`

```
[ResponseCache(CacheProfileName = "Default30")]
```

But my only concern is if this middleware is going to cache the response in the server side.
Cause I only want to have client caching side

here's what the doc says

> For server-side caching that follows the HTTP 1.1 Caching
> specification, use Response Caching Middleware.

They're saying **server-side caching**.

Also I have checked this question
[Response caching in ASP.NET Core work on client side or server side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799152/response-caching-in-asp-net-core-work-on-client-side-or-server-side)

and it says the same. That this middleware is working for server-side caching.

I don't want to have caching in my web server at all.
How can I just add the header in the response to tell my clients that they can cache this response?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the middleware. Response caching has two sides:

> Response caching reduces the number of requests a client or proxy
> makes to a web server. Response caching **also** reduces the amount of
> work the web server performs to generate a response.

First cache HTTP response in the client, only using `ResponseCache` attribute:

> The ResponseCache attribute sets response caching headers. Clients and
> intermediate proxies should honor the headers for caching responses
> under the HTTP 1.1 Caching specification.

Then if you want to cache response in the server too, You can use the response caching middleware.

> For server-side caching that follows the HTTP 1.1 Caching
> specification, use Response Caching Middleware. The middleware can use
> the ResponseCacheAttribute properties to influence server-side caching
> behavior.

[Read more ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-6.0)